# Benefit of html5 localstorage over cookies?

Tags: html, cookies, local-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Local Storage vs Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies)

What's the benefit of html5 local storage over cookies? I know local storage can run client side so potentially could have better performance, but what are the uses beyond this?

Comment: Depends on what your purpose is for storing the information. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies

Comment: I understand the potential performance benefits, but I was wondering if their are more fundamental changes? What will sites be able to do differently as a result? Thanks